# Reconcile Different Statements of the IRWLS Algorithm

Tags: self-study, generalized-linear-model, irls

Different textbooks seem to have different definitions for the weight matrix W in the Iteratively Re-Weighted Least Squares (IRWLS) algorithm.  They should be equivalent but I can't seem to piece it together.  As far as I can tell, there are no differences in any other part of the algorithm which would "cancel out" the differences.
I am considering, for example, Dobson and Faraway.

$W = diag(w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_n)$ where:

Method 1:

$$w_i = \Big[ V(\hat{\mu})(g'(\hat{\mu}))^2 \Big]^{-1}$$

Method 2:

$$w_i = \Big[ Var(y_i)(g'(\hat{\mu}))^2 \Big]^{-1}$$

Please note the variance function $V(\mu)$ is not the same as the variance of the distribution of $Y$, $Var(y_i)$.  What's the discrepancy?  Is the second dropping a dispersion parameter to "simplify" the exposition?  Which one should I use?

Which is the most general?

I realize IRWLS is implemented, but I need to know for my coursework.